# Nested for loop over objects that returns unique key value pair dict

Tags: python, django

Maybe a title is confusing but here is my problem.

I go through django model objects with nested for loop as below. In the end I want to have dictionary which has unique key value pairs.

Below code works but I don't feel that it's really efficient.

```
settings = []
for feature in features:
    for setting in feature.settings.all():
        settings.append({"name": setting.name, "active": setting.active})
return [dict(t) for t in {tuple(setting.items()) for setting in settings}]
```

so before return I am having something like this:
`[{'name': 'x', 'active': False}, {'name': 'y', 'active': True}, {'name': 'x', 'active': False}]`

but when I return I remove duplicates in the list and return below.
`[{'name': 'x', 'active': False}, {'name': 'y', 'active': True}]`

Comment: sorry, you are right. it shouldn't be `settings` but only `setting.items`.
i just edited. it's working now

Comment: dictionaries have "unique key value pairs" by definition

Comment: how do you want to define "unique"? which values do you want to keep/drop?

Comment: well, what i want is this: 
for example I have `[{'name': 'x', 'active': False}, {'name': 'y', 'active': True}, {'name': 'x', 'active': False}`

so in the end I should have list with 2 dictionaries as there is duplicated one

Comment: perhaps `list(set(settings))` is all you need then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres, you can use distinct with a fields attribute, and then use values, to get your settings as desired,

your code would be equivalent to:

```
feature.settings.distinct('name', 'active').values('name', 'active')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension, if this is what you meant.

```
print({setting.name : setting.active for feature in features for setting in feature.settings.all()})
```

If the line gets too long, you can use something like this.

```
print({
    setting.name : setting.active
    for feature in features
    for setting in feature.settings.all()
})
```

Comment: this is almost what I want but it's only makes a dict but I want list of dictionaries